# data.table aggregation based on multiple criteria

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to calculate how many pid within a set fid's have a yob smaller than person's yob. The second question is about unique pid. Updating the question based on efforts @langtang and my own reflections:

```
#Libraries:
library(data.table)
library(tictoc)

#Make it replicable:
set.seed(1)

#Define parameters of the simulation:
pid<-1:1000
fid<-1:5
time_periods<-1:12
yob<-sample(seq(1900,2010),length(pid),replace = TRUE)

#Obtain in how many firms a given pid works in a givem month:
nr_firms_pid_time<-sample(1:length(fid),length(pid),replace = TRUE)

#This means:
#First pid:  works in first firm;
#Second pid: works in first four firms;
#Third pid:  works in first firm;
#Fourth pid: works in two firms.

#Aux functions:
function_rep<-function(x){
  rep(1:12,x)
}

function_seq<-function(x){
  1:x
}

#Create panel
data_panel<-data.table(pid = rep(pid,nr_firms_pid_time*length(time_periods)))
data_panel[,yearmonth:=do.call(c,sapply(nr_firms_pid_time,function_rep))]
data_panel[,fid:=rep(do.call(c,sapply(nr_firms_pid_time,function_seq)),each = 12)]

#Merge in yob:
data_yob<-data.table(pid = pid,yob = yob)
data_panel<-merge(data_panel,data_yob,by = c("pid"),all.x = TRUE)

#Remove not needed stuff:
rm(pid)
rm(fid)
rm(time_periods)
rm(yob)
rm(data_yob)

#Solution 1 (terribly slow):
# make a small function that counts the number of coworkers with
# earlier dob than this individual
older_coworkers = function(id,yrmonth) {
  #First obtain firms in which a worker works in a given month:
  id_firms<-data_panel[pid==id&yearmonth==yrmonth,fid]
  
  #Then extract data at a given month:
  data_func<-data_panel[(fid %in% id_firms)&(yearmonth==yrmonth)]
  
  #Then extract his dob:
  dob_to_use<-unique(data_func[pid==id,yob])
  sum(data_func[pid!=id]$yob<dob_to_use)
}

older_coworkers_unique = function(id,yrmonth) {
  #First obtain firms in which a worker works in a given month:
  id_firms<-data_panel[pid==id&yearmonth==yrmonth,fid]
  
  #Then extract data at a given month:
  data_func<-data_panel[(fid %in% id_firms)&(yearmonth==yrmonth)]
  
  #Then extract his dob:
  dob_to_use<-unique(data_func[pid==id,yob])
  
  #Get UNIQUE number of coworkers:
  sum(unique(data_func[pid!=id],by = c("pid"))$yob<dob_to_use)
}

#Works but is terrible slow:
tic()
sol_1<-data_panel[, .(older_coworkers(.BY$pid,.BY$yearmonth)),by = c("pid","yearmonth")]
toc()

#Solution 2 (better but do not like it, what if I want unique older coworkers)
function_older<-function(x){
  noc<-lapply(
    1:length(x),
    function(i){
      sum(x[-i]<x[i])
    }
  )
  unlist(noc)
}

#This is fast but I cannot get unique number:
tic()
sol_2<-data_panel[,.(pid,function_older(yob)),by = c("fid","yearmonth")][,sum(V2),by = c("pid","yearmonth")][order(pid,yearmonth)]
toc()

#Everything works:
identical(sol_1,sol_2)
```

The question is how to implement `older_coworkers_unique` in a very fast manner. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to provide a richer example dataset.  Also, why is there a duplicate row (pid=1, fid=1, ym=200801, dob=1950

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update, based on OP's new reproducible dataset

1. If you want a one-liner to reproduce `sol_2` above, you can do this:

```
data_panel[data_panel, on=.(yearmonth, fid, yob<yob )][, .N, by=.(i.pid, yearmonth)]
```

#### Explanation:

The above is using a non-equi join, which can be a helpful approach when using data.table. I am joining `data_panel` on itself, requiring that yearmonth and fid be equal, but that year of birth (left side of join) is less than year of birth (right side of join). This will return a data.table where firms and yearmonth matches, but where every older coworker (`pid`) is matched to their  younger coworkers (`i.pid`). We can thus count the rows (.N) by each younger coworker (`i.pid`) and `yearmonth`.  This produces the same as `sol_1` and `sol_2` above. You commented that you would like to find the unique coworkers, and so the second approach below does that, by using `len(unique(pid))` as below, in Option 2.

2. The same non-equi join approach can be used to get **unique** older coworkers, like this:

```
data_panel[data_panel, on=.(yearmonth, fid, yob<yob )] %>% 
  .[, .(older_coworkers = length(unique(pid))), by=.(i.pid, yearmonth)]
```

#### Previous Response, based on OP's original very small example dataset

I'm not sure exactly what you want the output to look like. However in your example data, I first drop the duplicate row (because I couldn't understand why it was there (see my comment above)), and then I apply a function that counts that number of older coworkers for each pid/fid/ym.

```
# make your example data unique
data=unique(data)

# make a small function that counts the number of coworkers with
# earlier dob than this individual
older_coworkers = function(birth,firm,yrmonth,id) {
  data[dob<birth & fid==firm & ym==yrmonth & pid!=id,.N]
}

# apply the function to the data
data[, .(num_older_coworkers = older_coworkers(dob,.BY$fid, .BY$ym, .BY$pid)), by=.(pid,fid,ym)]
```

Output:

```
   pid fid     ym num_older_coworkers
1:   1   1 200801                   1
2:   1   2 200802                   0
3:   2   1 200801                   0
4:   3   2 200801                   0
```

- Person 1 at Firm 1 has one older coworker in the month of 2008-01 -- that is, Person 2 at Firm 1 in 2008-01.
- Person 1 at Firm 2 (born in 1950) would also have an older coworker, namely, Person 3 at Firm 2 (born in 1930), but the result shows 0, because Person 1 at Firm 2 ym (i.e. 2008-01) does not match with that potential older coworker's ym (i.e. 2008-02).

Comment: @Vitalijs, I think you can do this with a single non-equi join - see updated answer

Comment: thanks for the solution. Can you explain your one-liners? ```data_panel[data_panel, on=.(yearmonth, fid, yob<yob )][, .N, by=.(i.pid, yearmonth)]``` this looks a bit cryptic.

Comment: sure, see added explanation above